# What are some relationships between a matrix and its transpose?

Tags: linear-algebra

All I can think of are that
If symmetric, they're equivalent

If A is orthogonal, then its transpose is equivalent to its inverse.

They have the same rank and determinant.

Is there any relationship between their images/kernels or even eigenvalues?

Comment: When square, their eigenvalues are the same. Unsurprisingly, the left nullspace of one is the right nullspace of the other, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 6):

The key to understanding the various relations between a matrix and its transpose is to understand what the transpose of a matrix signifies. For simplicity, let's work over the field $\mathbb R$. Recall that for a vector space $V$, its dual, $V^*$, is the vector space of linear functionals: linear transformations $\varphi :V\to \mathbb R$.

Here is an exercise then to explain what transposing a matrix does:

1) Given a linear transformation $T:V\to W$, one obtains a function $T^*:W^*\to V^*$, given by $T^*(\varphi)(v)=\varphi(T(v))$. Actually, $T^*$ is a linear transformation.

2) Fix bases $B_V=(v_1,\cdots, v_n)$ and $B_W=(w_1, \cdots, w_k)$ for $V$ and $W$ respectively (here each $v_i$ is a vector in $V$, each $w_i$ is a vector in $W$). Let $M$ be the matrix representing $T$ in these bases.

3) Recall the dual bases $B^*_{V^*}$ and $B^*_{W^*}$. Prove that the matrix representing $T^*$ with respect to these bases is precisely the transpose of $M$.

Understanding the transpose via the dual spaces explains a lot.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what it explains?

Comment: @Shahab since it reveals the transpose to essentially be precomposing with $T$, the contravariant properties of transposition (e.g., $(AB)^t=B^tA^t$) as well as the additive properties are immediate. Further, for instance, it shows that the determinant and the inverse of a matrix commute with its transpose (and the immediate consequence that they share the same characteristic polynomial, minimal polynomials, etc.). It also shows that they have the same rank.

Answer (score 4):

Fix a ring $R$, and let $A \in M_n(R)$.  The characteristic polynomial for $A$ is $$\chi_A(x)=\det (xI-A),$$
so that $\chi_{A^T}(x) = \det (x I -A^T)= \det ((xI-A)^T)=\det(xI-A)$.  Since the eigenvalues of $A$ and $A^T$ are the roots of their respective characteristic polynomials, $A$ and $A^T$ have the same eigenvalues.  (Moreover, they have the same characteristic polynomial.)

It follows that $A$ and $A^T$ have the same minimal polynomial as well, because the minimal polynomial arises as the radical of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: At the end of your answer, what is the definition of the "radical of a polynomial"?

Answer (score 3):

There is a very strong connection between an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ and its transpose $A^T$, at least if the base field is $\def\R{\mathbb{R}}\R$.

Denote by $C(A)$ the column space, that is, the subspace of $\R^m$ generated by the columns of $A$. Denote by $N(A)$ the null space, that is, the set of vectors $v\in\R^n$ such that $Av=0$.

Associated to a matrix $A$ we have four subspaces:

- $C(A)\subseteq\R^m$
- $N(A)\subseteq\R^n$
- $C(A^T)\subseteq\R^n$
- $N(A^T)\subseteq\R^m$

Now the relations (of course, the second one is equivalent to the first)

$$
C(A)\oplus N(A^T)=\R^m,\qquad
C(A^T)\oplus N(A)=\R^n
$$

which means that every vector of $\R^m$ can be written in one and only one way as the sum of a vector in $C(A)$ and one in $N(A^T)$.

To see why, consider a vector $v\in C(A)\cap N(A^T)$; then $v=Ax$ for some $x\in\R^n$ because $v\in C(A)$; since also $v\in N(A^T)$ we get
$$
0=A^Tv=A^TAx
$$
from which we deduce
$$
0=x^T0=A^TAx=(Ax)^T(Ax),
$$
so that $Ax=0$ and therefore $v=Ax=0$. Thus $C(A)\cap N(A^T)=\{0\}$ and we only need to show that $C(A)+N(A^T)=\R^m$.

The relation between the rank of $A$ and of $A^T$ and the "rank-nullity theorem" tell then that
$$
\dim N(A^T)=m-\mathrm{rk}\,A^T=m-\mathrm{rk}\,A=m-\dim C(A),
$$
so that $\dim C(A)+\dim N(A^T)=m=\dim\R^m$ and hence $C(A)+N(A^T)=\R^m$.

The same holds for matrices over $\def\C{\mathbb{C}}\C$, but using the Hermitian transpose instead of the transpose.

---

This doesn't hold however for matrices over an arbitrary field, because the step “$(Ax)^T (Ax)=0$ implies $Ax=0$” cannot be done in general.